# My Sites Error -There was a problem retrieving the latest activity. Please try again later

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, newsfeed

I've had some problems with Distributed Cache with SharePoint 2013 which I think are resolved, however in the newsfeed section of MySites the following error is visible:

> SharePoint returned the following error: The operation failed because the server could not access the distributed cache. Internal type name: Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal error code: 55. Contact your system administrator for help in resolving this problem.

I found the following [article](http://alstechtips.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/sharepoint-2013-operation-failed.html) that explained that there could be something wrong with UPA permissions, but not sure how to perform the solution that's been explained in the article. It mentions:

> Grant the UPA service account Full Control in the UPA Connect Permissions for User Profile Service.

So when the User Profile Service Application is selected > permissions, the farm account (running Timer Job) is already present with Full control. Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

One of the Service accounts needed to be added to the Admin section of the UPA.